# How to make independent toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript

So that everyone opens their own content.
Making an individual identifier is a bad idea, there are 1000 such buttons

```
  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">1</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">2</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">3</h1>


<style>
  .hide{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

```
let userSection = document.querySelector(".toggle__elements");
let isShow = true

function showHide(){
  isShow=!isShow
  userSection.classList.toggle("hide", isShow);
}
```

Comment: Maybe look into making use of ```data attributes``` or ```ID's``` for your elements to allow you to select the individual selections.

Comment: Do you have 1000 toggles and dont want to assign an id to each ? Can you render them out dynamically and add an id that way? Or maybe select all toggles and use their index to set their state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `window.event`, from inside the event handler, to grab the event fired and fetch its target property to get the element firing the event.

Once you have the button that got clicked, you can use a strategy like getting its next sibling like I did here on this demo, and toggle the hide class.

```js
function showHide(){
  const elementClicked = window.event.target;  
  const elementNextToClickedOne = elementClicked.nextElementSibling;    
  elementNextToClickedOne.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.toggle__button{
  cursor: pointer;
}  
  
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">1</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">2</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide()" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">3</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your function to work independently for each button. The comments inside the snippet should provide some information on how this is achieved. The most notable thing here is that we can use `this` in `onclick="showHide(this)"` to pass down the instance of our button element to the `showHide` function. Which allows us to select the correct sibling element and toggle its `hide` class.

```js
function showHide(button){
  const userSection = button.nextSibling.nextElementSibling; // Select the next sibling of the clicked button
  userSection.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showHide(this)" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">1</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide(this)" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">2</h1>


  <button onclick="showHide(this)" class="toggle__button">click</button>
  <h1 class="toggle__elements hide">3</h1>


<style>
  .hide{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```